# Page is refreshing after an image upload in using ASP.NET core & AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I have read somewhere that when an image is uploaded & there is a problem with it the page will refresh and abort the upload, but when I upload the image, I can see the image being displayed on my page and then the page gets refreshed, any ideas on what is causing that?

The AJAX code that sends the image to the server :

```
function uploadAuth() {
var formdata = new FormData($('#formt')[0]);

if ($("#file").val() !== "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Actions/UploadImage',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var d = data;
            $('.userPicturesAuth').append('<div class="singleImage"><img class= "img" src=" ' + data + ' "/><button class="dropdowncust butt fas fa-ellipsis-v"><div class="dropdown-contentcust"><div class="singleElement"><p>Change picture</p></div><div class="singleElement"><p>Delete picture</p></div><div class="singleElement"><p>Make private</p></div></div></button></div>');
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

}

server code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string UploadImage(Service service, IFormFile photo)
    {
        if (photo != null)
        {
            using var image = Image.Load(photo.OpenReadStream());
            string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(Hosting.WebRootPath, "images");
            image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(180, 180));
            var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
            image.Save(filePath);
            
            //photo.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            var newPath = filePath.Replace(Hosting.WebRootPath, "");
            
            return newPath;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

the Path that is returned to the ajax as a response is :

```
\images\ab89e973-d434-4053-8efa-d2a17847b06e_6682_DancingCoffin4.png
```

-------EDIT-------

the whole HTML page:

```
    @using Models
@using AutoMatcherProject.ViewModels
@model Models.GenericUser
@using Utils
@using Interfaces
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using DbServices

@inject ICredentialDb DataAccess
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> signIn


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/jQuery-Autocomplete-master/"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/css/myCss.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/css/AuthUserCss.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arya' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="~/js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/AuthenticatedUserScripts.js"></script>
        <script src="~/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link href="~/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
              rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/css/metro-all.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>

    </head>


@{
    var user = DataAccess.GetById(signIn.GetUserId(User));
    var username = user.Username;
    var password = user.Password;
    var allServices = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Service)).Cast<Service>().ToList();
    List<Service>? services = null;
    List<Service>? unsubscribedServices = new List<Service>();
    try
    {

        services = DataAccess.GetUserServicesById(signIn.GetUserId(User));
        for (int i = 0; i < allServices.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!services.Contains(allServices[i]))
            {
                unsubscribedServices.Add(allServices[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    if (services.Count != 0)
    {
        <div id="mainCont">
            <div id="cont1">
                <label class="aryaFont">Welcome Back @username!</label>
                <div id="userServices">
                    <label class="aryaFont">Select a service</label>

                    <br />
                    @*<form method="post" asp-action="ChangeDescriptions" asp-controller="Actions">
                            @for (int i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <input name="services" type="checkbox" value="@services[i]" />

                                @Html.Hidden("id", @signIn.GetUserId(User));
                                <label id="serviceName">@services[i]</label>
                                <br />

                            }
                            <input type="text" name="description" value="" />
                            <button>Change description!</button>
                        </form>*@


                    <form id="schedulerFormAuth">
                        <div id="dropDownAuthenticated">
                            @*<select id="userServicesDropDownAuth" class="browser-default custom-select" asp-for="Service" onchange="getImages(this, '@username', '@password')">
                                        @{
                                            <option style="display:none"></option>
                                            foreach (var item in services)
                                            {
                                                <option>@item.ToString()</option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                </select>*@
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div id="likesAuth">
                            <label class="aryaFont">Select number of likes</label>
                            <br />
                            <input id="likesInputAuth" class="likeInput" asp-for="Likes" onchange="flipLikesAuth()">
                            <br />
                            <div id="checkboxAuth">
                                <label class="aryaFont">Start liking in the future?</label>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="onOffAuth">
                                        <div class="onoffswitchAuth">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitchAuth" class="onoffswitch-checkboxAuth" id="myonoffswitchAuth" checked>
                                            <label class="onoffswitch-labelAuth" for="myonoffswitchAuth">
                                                <span class="onoffswitch-innerAuth"></span>
                                                <span class="onoffswitch-switchAuth"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="dateAuth">
                                        <label class="aryaFont"> When would you like us to start?</label>
                                        <div class="container">

                                            <input id="datetimepicker1Auth" asp-for="Time" type="datetime-local" asp-format="{4:MM/dd/yyyy}" class="form-control" />
                                            <button id="dateAuth" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="submitAuth" onclick="submitValidatedFormAuth('@username','@password')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue 1">
                                    <i id="pleaseWait" class="text-danger"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="checkOutAuth">
                    <input id="StartLikingAuth" onclick="scheduleAuth()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Check out and start likiing!">
                </div>
                <div id="descriptionAuth">
                    <form id="aboutMeAuth">
                        <h5>Change About Me</h5>
                        <i>About Me</i>
                        <input id="aboutMeInput" type="text" asp-for="input" />
                        <br />
                        <a id="aboutMe"></a>
                        <br />
                        <input onclick="aboutMeAuth()" asp-for="input" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Change About Me">
                    </form>
                    <br />
                    <form id="autoCompleteForm">
                        <i>Change location</i>
                        <input id="autocomplete2" asp-for="input" type="text">
                        <br />
                        <a id="currentLocation"> </a>
                        <br />
                        <input onclick="getCityAuth()" asp-for="input" type="button" value="Set Location" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </form>
                    <i>I am looking for:</i>
                    <br />
                    <form name="genders">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="Male">
                            <label for="Male">Male</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Both" id="Both">
                            <label for="Both">Both</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="Female">
                            <label for="Female">Female</label>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <br />
                    <label for="customRange1">Change searching distance</label>
                    <input type="range" class="custom-range" id="distanceInput" min="0" max="160" value="" oninput="distanceoutput.value = value "><output id="distanceoutput"></output>
                    <br />
                    <input data-role="doubleslider"
                           data-min="18" data-max="80"
                           onchange="$('#slider-return-value').val(this.value)">
                    <input type="text" id="slider-return-value">
                    <input onclick="changeSearchSettings()" asp-for="input" type="button" value="Update Settings" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <br />
                    <div class="userPicturesAuth">
                        <div class="addPicture">
                            <div class="pictureSquare">
                                <div class="camIcon">
                                    <i class="fas fa-camera fa-3x ">
                                    </i><div class="addAPicture">
                                        <form id="formt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            <input onchange="uploadAuth()" id="file" asp-for="Photo" type="file" />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            @if (unsubscribedServices.Count > 0)
            {
                <div id="cont2">
                    <div class="botImage">
                        @*<img src="~/images/unnamed.png" alt="Alternate Text" />*@
                    </div>
                    <div id="cn1">
                        <form id="schedulerForm">
                            <div id="service">
                                <label class="aryaFont">Select a service</label>
                                <br />
                                <select id="service" class="browser-default custom-select" asp-for="Service" onchange="flipService()">

                                    @{
                                        <option style="display:none"></option>
                                        foreach (var singleService in unsubscribedServices)
                                        {
                                            <option>@singleService.ToString()</option>
                                        };
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div id="likes">
                                <label class="aryaFont">Select number of likes</label>
                                <br />
                                <input id="likesInput" class="likeInput" asp-for="Likes" onchange="flipLikes()">
                                <br />
                                <div id="checkbox">
                                    <label class="aryaFont">Start liking in the future?</label>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="onoffswitch">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
                                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="date">
                                            <label class="aryaFont"> When would you like us to start?</label>
                                            <div class="container">

                                                <input id="datetimepicker1" asp-for="Time" type="datetime-local" asp-format="{4:MM/dd/yyyy}" class="form-control" />
                                                <button id="date" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input id="submit" onclick="submitForm()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <form id="serviceLogIn">
                            <div>
                                <i id="error" class="text-danger"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input id="username1" type="text" asp-for="Username" value="Username" />
                                <br />
                                <input id="password1" type="password" asp-for="Password" value="Password" />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <input id="submitService" onclick="validateUser()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Validate">
                            <br />
                            <i id="pleaseWait" class="text-danger"></i>

                            <div class="spinner-border"></div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="checkOut">
                        <h5>Checkout form</h5>
                        <input id="StartLiking" onclick="schedule()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Check out and start likiing!">
                    </div>
                    <div id="description">
                        <form id="ChangeDesc">
                            <h5>Change Description</h5>
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Proffesion" /> <i>Proffesion</i>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="CompanyName" /><i>Company name</i>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="School" /><i>School or university</i>
                            <br />
                            <input onclick="changeDesc()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Change Description">
                        </form>
                        <br />
                        <form id="autoCompleteForm">
                            <input id="autocomplete2" asp-for="input" type="text"><i>Change location</i>
                            <br />
                            <input onclick="getCity()" asp-for="input" type="button" value="Set Location" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </form>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="userPictures">
                        <div class="addPicture">
                            <div class="pictureSquare">
                                <div class="camIcon">
                                    <i class="fas fa-camera fa-3x "></i>
                                    <div class="addAPicture">
                                        @*<form id="formt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                <input onchange="upload()" id="file" asp-for="Photo" type="file" /><input id="service2" asp-for="Service" />
                                                <i>
                                                    Add a
                                                </i>
                                            </form>*@
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div id="cont2">

            <div id="cn1">
                <form id="schedulerForm">
                    <div id="service">
                        <label class="aryaFont">Select a service</label>
                        <br />
                        <select id="service" class="browser-default custom-select" asp-for="Service" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Service>()" onchange="flipService()">
                            <option style="display:none" />
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="likes">
                        <label class="aryaFont">Select number of likes</label>
                        <br />
                        <input id="likesInput" class="likeInput" asp-for="Likes" onchange="flipLikes()">
                        <br />
                        <div id="checkbox">
                            <label class="aryaFont">Start liking in the future?</label>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <br />
                                <div class="onoffswitch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox switchunauth" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
                                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div id="date">
                                    <label class="aryaFont"> When would you like us to start?</label>
                                    <div class="container">

                                        <input id="datetimepicker1" asp-for="Time" type="datetime-local" asp-format="{4:MM/dd/yyyy}" class="form-control" />
                                        <button id="date" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="submit" onclick="submitForm()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div>
                <form id="serviceLogIn">
                    <div>
                        <i id="error" class="text-danger"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="username1" type="text" asp-for="Username" value="Username" />
                        <br />
                        <input id="password1" type="password" asp-for="Password" value="Password" />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <input id="submitService" onclick="validateUser()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Validate">
                    <br />
                    <i id="pleaseWait" class="text-danger"></i>

                    <div class="spinner-border"></div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="checkOut">
                <h5>Checkout form</h5>
                <input id="StartLiking" onclick="schedule()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Check out and start likiing!">
            </div>
            <div id="description">
                <form id="ChangeDesc">
                    <h5>Change Description</h5>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Proffesion" /> <i>Proffesion</i>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" asp-for="CompanyName" /><i>Company name</i>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" asp-for="School" /><i>School or university</i>
                    <br />
                    <input onclick="changeDesc()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Change Description">
                </form>
                <br />
                <form id="autoCompleteForm">
                    <input id="autocomplete2" asp-for="input" type="text"><i>Change location</i>
                    <br />
                    <input onclick="getCity()" asp-for="input" type="button" value="Set Location" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
                <br />
                <div class="userPictures">
                    <div class="addPicture"><div class="pictureSquare"><div class="camIcon"><i class="fas fa-camera fa-3x "></i><div class="addAPicture"><form id="formt" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input onchange="upload()" id="file" asp-for="Photo" type="file" /><input id="service2" asp-for="Service" /><i>Add a picture</i></form></div></div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a form to trigger this ajax you have to make sure the form doesn't submit

Comment: it is a form 
form id="formt" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input onchange="uploadAuth()" id="file" asp-for="Photo" type="file" />

what do you mean doesn't submit?

Comment: How is your `uploadAuth()` function triggered? If through a submit button then add `e.preventDefault()` before your formData variable. The add `e` as a parameter in your function like this `function uploadAuth(e)`

Comment: the input type is not button, its -"file", 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.inputtaghelper.inputtypename?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: when I pass e to the function e is undefined

Comment: Could you please post the details codes about your current view? If you could post more details codes, we could reproduce the issue and find the  reason.

Comment: @BrandoZhang you mean the whole HTML?

Comment: The html part which related with uploadAuth. If your page is not very big, I suggest you could post the whole view.

Comment: @BrandoZhang hey, I added the whole HTML page, sorry for the delay

Comment: According to your codes, I still couldn't reproduce your issue on my side, it will not refresh the page after uploading files. If possible, please remove other personal information and other codes, then upload a sample on the github for me to reproduce this issue?